# How update MySql Database from Datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to update my MySql database from a datagridview which I have applied changes to.

This is my code in which I apply changes and validations to my datagridview. Once those changes have been applied I want to update it in my MYSQL table.

```
private void btndepurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_CASE"].Value = Valida_Cc(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_CASE"].Value.ToString());
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["BALANCE"].Value = validar_balance(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["BALANCE"].Value.ToString());
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_CITY"].Value = FixCourtCities(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_CITY"].Value.ToString());
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COMMENTS"].Value = Validar_Com(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COMMENTS"].Value.ToString());
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_NUMBER"].Value = Validar_Cn(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_NUMBER"].Value.ToString(),
                    (Int32)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["LINK_REFERENCE"].Value, dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["COURT_CASE"].Value.ToString());
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["PROCESS_TYPE"].Value = Validar_Pt(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["PROCESS_TYPE"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This button should apply the change, but I don't get it. My code

```
   private void MySql_Update()
    {

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(configuracion.conexion);

        string query = "SELECT * FROM TEST.PRUEBA;";

        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            myadapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myadapter);
            myadapter.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();


            myadapter.Fill(dtTable);
            myadapter.FillSchema(dtTable, SchemaType.Source);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dtTable;

            myadapter.Update(dtTable);
            createLog("llegamos aqui " + dtTable);

            //bindingSource.DataSource = dtTable;

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            createLog(ex.ToString());
        }
    }


private void btnActualizarBD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySql_Update();
        MessageBox.Show("UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY");
        /*
        */
    }
```

I can't update my bd, help me please.!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TEST.PRUEBA` does not perform any updates, you need an `UPDATE` query instead

Comment: but with this sentence I update in the database what is in the datagridview:  `table.Rows.Add(dataGridView2);
                myadap.Update(table);`